# How can I disable minimizing window in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, window, obs-studio

I need to prevent my Ubuntu to minimize windows (it would be better if I could choose which one specifically). Is there any way to do it? I need it for OBS Studio, because it stops showing any window when minimized, but this is something that can be done easily by accident, and the quality of a video reduces due to such accidents. Thanks.

Comment: Right click on the app's title bar and chose "always on top".

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the button for all windows, assuming you're on default GNOME distribution, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':maximize,close'
```

To only do it while streaming, you can use [Advanced Scene Switcher](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/advanced-scene-switcher.395/) with 2 macros that contain the following actions:

- running the command above
- running this command to bring minimize button back:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

and as condition you could check if you began/ended **Recording**.